# Javascript Validation Form

Tags: javascript

I am working with a form that has a catcha image. When a user fills out the form, and presses submit ( and only when the captcha number is wrong) the fields are reset or cleared. How can I prevent this from happening?
If a visitor fills out the form, presses submit, the expected behaviour is theform is submitted, or if the captch number is wrong, retain the information that the visitor had input in the fields and ask the visitor to fill in the correct captcha number...

Here is the js:

```
function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
if (document.getElementById){
var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
  if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
    if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
      if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
    } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
      if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
      if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
        min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
        if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
  } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
} if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
} }
```

Comment: ... what's processing the form on the back end? I think you're looking  for a way to make the form 'sticky' and that involves work on the server as well. Captcha should also get validated on the server side. I'd suggest looking at some tutorials for ReCaptcha processing to get you started as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to prevent the default behaviour you've to use a callback function like this:

```
function onsubmit_handler(evt) {
    if (/* validation is ok */) {
       return true;
    }
    else { /* validation is not ok */
       evt.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
}

yourfom.onsubmit = onsubmit_handler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in believing that the captcha is validated (only) on the *server* after a successful validation by the JS (i.e., not via an Ajax call in the form submission event handler)? Am I further correct in believing that you're doing a true HTML form submission instead of an Ajax form submission in the background?

If both of those are true, then the problem probably isn't in your JavaScript at all (I say "probably" only because you could conceivably have a JS function that clears all the form fields on load or something like that). You're submitting the form to the server, the server looks at the captcha, sees that the answer is wrong, and displays the form again -- with blank values. You need to change your *server code* to include the user's previous answers as `value` attributes (or `selected` `option`s or whatever as appropriate for the element type) when it writes the form after a server-side validation failure.